# Javascript: Loop through unknown number of object literals

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects all named in this fashion:

```
var p1 = {};
var p2 = {};
p1.name = "john";
p1.hobby = "collects stamps";
p2.name = "jane";
p2.hobby = "collects antiques";
```

I know how to loop through p1 and p2 to collect the properties, provided I know how many of these p object literals there are. Here's my problem, I don't always know how many of these p object literals there will be. Sometimes it goes up to p2, sometimes it goes up to p20.

Is there a way to loop through objects if I know they all share the same prefix?

Edit: I can't change how I'm getting the list of objects. It's given to me in that format...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we make the following assumptions:

- The objects are global
- The number suffixes are sequential

...then the following works:

```
for (var i = 1; window["p" + i] !== undefined; i++) {
    console.log(window["p" + i]); // loop over each object here
}
```

Comment: so basically test for p# to see if it's undefined, and if it's not, read properties of p#, and if it is undefined, I can stop? let me test this and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: +1 Heh, I just added this solution to my answer, but didn't even see yours until just now!

Answer (score 2):

You should have them in an Array referenced by a single variable.

```
var p = [];
p.push({   
    name:"john",
    hobby:"collects stamps"
}, {
    name:"jane",
    hobby:"collects antiques"
});
```

Then you'd loop the Array, and enumerate each object...

```
for( var i = 0; i < p.length; i++ ) {
    for( var n in p[i] ) {
        console.log( p[i][n] );
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems from a comment that these may be *arriving* as individual variable.

If they're global variables, and if they always have the same `p1` naming, then you can access them as properties of the global `window` object.

```
var obj;

for( var i = 1; obj = window['p' + i]; i++ ) {
    if( typeof obj === 'object' ) {
        for( var n in obj ) {
            console.log( obj[n] );
        }
    }
}
```

This loop will run until a `p(n)` global returns a falsey value.

So as long as a truthy value is found, and its `typeof` is `'object'`, you'll iterate that object.

Comment: Ok. I like where this is going. So suppose I have no control over how the data is given to me. How do I push an unknown number of objects into a single array?

Comment: @newbieProgrammer: How is the data currently given? Are you saying that the objects are added to the script as individual `p1`, `p2`, etc. variables? If so, that makes things a little different.

Comment: yes, you're exactly right. The data given to me is as individual p# object literals.

Comment: @newbieProgrammer: If they're global variables, then you can access them as properties of the `window` object. I added a solution to my answer.

Comment: ...nevermind, I see that this solution has [already been given](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9116237/1106925)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store them all in one top-level object literal? It will make it easier to enumerate through them.

EG:

```
var MyObj = {
    p1: {},
    p2: {}
};
```

etc..

[edit]

If they are local vars, are you can't change the format of this data, you might have to use eval.
Don't shoot me:

```
var p1 = {};
var p2 = {};
p1.name = "john";
p1.hobby = "collects stamps";
p2.name = "jane";
p2.hobby = "collects antiques";

var found = true, c = 1;

while(found) {
    try {
        var obj = eval('p' + c);
        c++;
        console.log(obj);
    } catch(e){
        found = false;
    }
}
```

I don't suggest using this, I suggest changing the format of the data you are receiving, but this is one possible solution.

Comment: I can't control how I'm receiving the list of objects. So to store them all in a single top-level object literal would require some finesse, since I have to read in the input and then reformat before looping through it. If that's the only way, I'll do that.

Comment: How exactly are you receiving the list of objects? What scope are you receiving them in?

Comment: I'm receiving the list of objects from a response of a post call. So the post response comes to me as plain text, and when I read it, the scope is just what you see.

Comment: You should be transferring this data in JSON format rather.. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Yes, you're right in that this would be much better in JSON format. Unfortunately, I have no control over how the web service spits out the data to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all your data stored in a variable , or a few variables you can push it into the array.

```
var data = "....JSON";
var a = [];
a.push(data);
```

Push keeps adding stuff into the array in basic sense.
You could also pop to remove the last pushed data.

Take a look at the other methods here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array